# Ember.js architecture for dashboard application

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm starting to work with Ember. It looks that it is a pretty good framework, I've read a lot of tutorials about binding, observers, views, objects etc. And I feel that I have good knowledge about the basic stuffs about Ember. I've made few small POCs. Now i want to build a dashboard, which will contains different kind of widgets (different size, layout, info, etc) and  those widgets will consume different API. I've seen a lot of examples like these ones:

http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/architecture-examples/emberjs/
http://andymatthews.net/code/emberWineshop/

But all of them are rendering identical lists of views. I'm trying to understand how can render different kind of views into my main dashboard view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into `Ember.ContainerView`. It lets you manage a collection of `childViews`, which can be anything that extends from `Ember.View`. That would be my approach if I was building a dashboard of "widgets".